# MySQL inner join with SUM displaying incorrect values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to generate a report containing the list of students with the fees dues. I have following tables.

```
students{**roll_number**, first_name, middle_name, last_name}
courses{**course_name**, semester, course_tuition_fees}
students_in_courses{**course_name, semester**, *roll_number*}
student_fee_payment{**receipt_number**, *roll_number*, fee_paid}
```

To display the fee dues for the students studying in all semester (1,2,3,4), I am using following query.

```
select s.roll_number, s.first_name,s.middle_name,s.last_name, 

                c.course_name, sin.semester, c.course_tuition_fees, SUM(sfp.fee_paid), (c.course_tuition_fees - SUM(sfp.fee_paid)) as balance

                from students s 

                INNER JOIN students_in_courses sin on s.roll_number = sin.roll_number 

                INNER JOIN courses c on sin.course_name = c.course_name 

                INNER JOIN student_fee_payment sfp on s.roll_number = sfp.roll_number 

                where c.course_name = 'B.Ed' AND sin.semester IN (1, 2, 3, 4) AND sfp.fee_type = 'Tuition Fees' AND sfp.fee_paid > 0

                group by s.roll_number, sin.course_name, sin.semester

                order by sin.semester ASC;
```

The query is returning the the records but displaying the sum(fee_paid) 4 times more than paid. Student named ALLAN WILKINSON has paid only 1100 but it is displaying 4400.

I have been struggling with this query for few hours now. Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

[image: Inner join displaying wrong calculation in sum method.]

Comment: "The query is returning the the records but displaying the sum(fee_paid) 4 times more than paid." -> use SUM in a delivered table (`... INNER JOIN ( SELECT ... ) AS alias ON ...` syntax) to make sure the SUM sums correctly without multiplying.. If you use SUM on joined tables the SUM most of the times are wrong because off JOIN multiplying..

Comment: "I have been struggling with this query for few hours now. Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated. " -> Provide a sqlfiddle,com with table structures and example data.. Also post expected results based on that example data..

Comment: Instead of `INNER JOIN courses c on sin.course_name = c.course_name` try `INNER JOIN courses c on sin.course_name = c.course_name && c.semester = sin.semester`

Comment: @Daniel1147 It is working now. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: Nice. Some of the results from original code will have different semester between table courses and table students_in_courses. That's why we need another constrain to make sure that 'semester's from two tables are the same.

Comment: @Daniel1147 Gotcha! In any case, I have both course_name and semester as composite primary keys in the table named students_in_courses. It was my mistake to not add another  constraint that checks for same semester. Thanks to your suggestion, it is working like a charm. Big thank you again.